# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setToAddresses(Set<String>) DM Mail

Tags: apex, email, email-template, class, apex-email-service

I have below mailing method where I am getting subject header as error.

Code:

```
Map<Id,String> ManagerMap= new Map<Id,String>(); 
        Map<Id,String> RepMap= new Map<Id,String>(); 
        Map<Id,String> RepNameMap= new Map<Id,String>(); 
        for (Compliance_Incident_abv__c myContact : [select ID,ManagerEmail_abv__c,RepEmail_abv__c,Rep_abv__c,Rep_abv__r.Name from Compliance_Incident_abv__c  where ID in :selIncs]) {
        ManagerMap.put(mycontact.Id , mycontact.ManagerEmail_abv__c);
        RepMap.put(mycontact.Id , mycontact.RepEmail_abv__c);
        RepNameMap.put(mycontact.id , mycontact.Rep_abv__r.Name);
        system.debug('ManagerMap@'+ManagerMap);
        system.debug('RepMap@'+RepMap);
        system.debug('RepNameMap@'+RepNameMap);
        }

         List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
         List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailsDM = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (Compliance_Incident_abv__c myContact : selIncs) {
        sendTo.clear();
        ccTo.clear();  

      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = 
      new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mailDM = 
      new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      sendTo.add(RepMap.get(myContact.ID)); 
      mail.setToAddresses(sendTo); // This line though same not errored out
      sendToDM.add(ManagerMap.get(mycontact.ID));
      mailDM.setToAddresses(sendToDM); // This line gets error 
       mail.setSenderDisplayName('Abbvie IT Team');
         mail.SetSaveAsActivity(false);
     mailDM.setSenderDisplayName('Abbvie IT Team');
         mailDM.SetSaveAsActivity(false);
      ccTo.add(ManagerMap.get(mycontact.Id));
      mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);
      mail.setTargetObjectId(mycontact.Rep_abv__c);
      mailDM.setTargetObjectId(mycontact.Rep_abv__r.ManagerID);
      mail.setSubject('Initial Notification to Rep');
      mailDM.setSubject('Initial Notification to Manager');
      String body = 'Dear ' + RepNameMap.get(mycontact.ID) + ', ';
      body += '<br><br>What you need to know:';
      body += '<br>New ABS Incidents have been generated in iREP. Please review these incidents with your DM or Applicable Manager. There is no other action for you to complete in iREP.';
      body += '<br>To view your open incidents:<br>';
      body += '•       Log into the iREP app on your iPad and select “Compliance Incidents”<br>';
      body += '•       Select the “Open Incidents” View in the Compliance Incidents Home Page.<br>';
      body += '•       Click the Incident ID to view your incidents If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.<br>';

       String bodyDM = 'Dear ' + ManagerMap.get(mycontact.ID) + ', ';
       bodyDM += '<br><br>What you need to know:';
        bodyDM += '<br>New ABS Incident(s) have been published in iREP.';
        bodyDM += '<br>What you need to do:';
        bodyDM += '<br>•       Review the incident(s)';
        bodyDM += '<br>•       Coach your representative';
        bodyDM += '<br>•       Attest to the incident, submit, and sync iREP within two weeks, per ABS policy';
        bodyDM += '<br>If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.';

      mail.setHtmlBody(body);
      mailDM.setHtmlBody(bodyDM);
      mailsDM.add(mailDM);
    system.debug('@mails@'+mails);

  }
```

Comment: are both `sendTo` and `sendToDM` sets (collection) ?

Comment: Both are Set of Strings declared Public. Public Set<String> sendToDM = new set<String>();  Public Set<String> sendTo = new set<String>();

Comment: Use `List` or `String[]` instead and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**setToAddresses(toAddresses)**

> A list of email addresses to which you are sending the email. The
>   maximum number of email addresses allowed is 100. This argument is
>   allowed only when a template is not used.

I think you need to provide list here. you are using set(as specify in your question as i can't find where you declare `sendToDM`).

Comment: Please find SendToDM is just a Public set of string declared outside constructor.    Public Set<String> sendToDM = new set<String>();

Comment: You can only pass list as a variable in this method. You need to assign these value to list and then pass the list as a variable.